# TypeORM does not parse Enum to the PostgreSQL type

Tags: typescript, parsing, enums, migration, database-migration

Entity:

```
@Entity()
export class MyEntity {
  @Column({
    type: 'enum',
    enum: MyEnum,
    default: MyEnum.DEFAULT,
  })
  type: MyEnum;
}
```

Enum:

```
export enum MyEnum {
  DEFAULT = 1,
  NOT_DEFAULT = 2
}
```

Migration created by TypeORM:

```
await queryRunner.query(
  `CREATE TYPE "my_enum_type_enum" AS ENUM('1', '2')`,
);
await queryRunner.query(
  `ALTER TABLE "my_table" ADD "type" "my_enum_type_enum" NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'`,
);
```

---

Create the entity in code is working fine like the example below:

```
my_entity.type = MyEnum.DEFAULT; // "1" and "DEFAULT" does not work, but 1 (int) works
```

But when I try to save by the Repository I have an error:

```
invalid input value for enum my_enaum_type_enum: "DEFAULT"
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed following exactly the documentation: https://typeorm.io/#/entities/enum-column-type

```
export enum MyEnum {
  DEFAULT = "default",
  NOT_DEFAULT = "not_default"
}
```